# Php using GET method in URL, but input forms keep refreshing

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make users able to submit a form and that they're able to check calendar however, every time they click the next month, the input is cleared.

Here is the live example of the problem:

http://www.chanceity.com/test.php

I am setting months using this function

```
$month = @$_GET['month'];
$year = @$_GET['year'];

if($month == NULL)
{
    $date = getdate();
    $month = $date['month'];
    $year = $date['year'];
}

SetMonth($month,$year);
```

Clicking on the next month changes the URL to retrieve new information.

I think that's the cause of the problem however I would like to know if there's a better way or a way to avoid this.

Full code of 
getCalendar.php 
http://pastebin.com/fwp8hbFz

Trying to do this now instead with ajax.
So, I have a html file, that loads the php.
How would I go about showing next months in my getCalendar.php? if I am not using GET method.

Comment: Save the form data into sessions, check if the sessions exist in the value of the form element. `value="<?php isset($_SESSION['this_element_name']) ?: '';?>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use XHR (Ajax) request to reload the calendar without submitting form

OR

You can submit every informations from the input when you are changing month.

--

First method is the best

Comment: If I load it like function Refresh()
{
$('#calendarDiv').load('getCalendar.php')
};
When I press next month, only url changes and nothing else, form refreshes as well.

Comment: If you use XHR request the url must won't change.

Comment: Tried something from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp
Doesn't work, it has same behavior.

Comment: You are using a 'a' tag which redirect you to the current page. add a class on this link and in JS $('.the_class').on('click', function(event){event.preventDefault(); $('#calendarDiv').load('getCalendar.php?month=...'});

Answer (score 0):

The input is cleared because the page is reloaded when the user click next or previous month, and you don't save the values from your form.

You can use AJAX to retrieve your month and year, but you won't change your url to show your users the month and year (I don't know if you need it).

An option is to instead of use AJAX to retrieve your months, you can use AJAX to save in SESSION the user inputs. You can call this ajax in your **checkform** function.

**EDIT:**

HTML

```
<a onclick="return updateSession()" href="?month=September&amp;year=2014"><span class="alignright">&gt;&gt;</span></a>
```

JavaScript

```
updateSession() {
    $.post('file.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

file.php

```
$_SESSION = $_POST; // you can do something better here obviously
```

Comment: Now I am all confused. So by that I should create 2 buttons that are in index.html or whatever that actually request getCalendar.php again?

Comment: Now I saw that you don't submit any form, just generate an <a> with the url to the next and previous month. What you can do then is to add a onclick event in your <a> tag and call a function to use the ajax.

Comment: And in the ajax function you do something like: `$.post('file.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data) {});`. You can learn more about ajax using jquery here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: That link is part of the PHP, well actually its stored in text file as following
<table>rest of code to show pretty calendar
<a href = '?month=September&year=2014'><span class = 'alignright'>>></span></a></td></tr></table>??

Comment: Ahh guess I still need to learn about ajax, that got me even more confused there. But thanks for the help.